# restrict iOS app to A12/A12X Bionic chips

Tags: ios, arkit, info.plist

Apple says (https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/)

*"People occlusion and the use of motion capture, simultaneous front and back camera, and multiple face tracking are supported on devices with A12/A12X Bionic chips, ANE, and TrueDepth Camera."*

how do I restrict my arkit app to those devices only on the appstore ?

Comment: It’s detailed in the documentation as well: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/verifying_device_support_and_user_permission

Comment: this check can only be done at runtime when it's too late. I want the app to be only availble in the store to compatible devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply setting the project to A12 and above?

[image]

Comment: this doesn't ensure there's a TrueDepth Camera but it's better than nothing. thanks!